# NSButton makeFirstResponder

Tags: nsbutton, nsresponder

I have a simple Mac app with a window. In this window, I have two `NSTextfield`s and one `NSButton`.

When the window appears, the first `NSTextfield` has the focus. I press <kbd>enter</kbd> and the focus passes to the second `NSTextfield`. I press <kbd>enter</kbd> again and the focus passes to my button.

```
[myWindow makeFirstResponder:myButton];
```

This works fine but now when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> again, I expect that the button is clicked, but it does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, spacebar is what you press to select a button. This is the same for a selecting the value of a dropdown, radio button, or check button.